# Query not displaying distinct values using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a dropdown menu of `cat_id` which is present in table of `partner`. Currently I am getting duplicate values of `cat_id`. I want to get it only once. Please note partner id is drived from another table and they are more than one. Here is my code.

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM favourites WHERE user_id='$userid'");
if($query->num_rows != 0){
while ($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
  $partnerid = $rows['part_id'];
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT cat_id FROM partner WHERE
partner_id=$partnerid");
while ($rows = $query->fetch_assoc())
{
        $cat_id = $rows['cat_id'];
}}}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `GROUP_BY(cat_id)`?

Comment: please what do you mean by patner id is derived from another table.

Comment: i run this query on my machine it runs fine, please can u send a copy  of your query result

Comment: I tried using Group by. But didn't work.

Comment: Are you missing a join?...

Comment: no errors just getting duplicate results of $cat_id

Comment: What do you see if you do `print_r($query->fetch_all())` immediately after executing the 2nd query?

Comment: After print_r immediately after 2nd query, Result 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 90 [1] => 35 [2] => 32 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 91 [1] => 35 [2] => 2 [3] => 1 [4] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 92 [1] => 35 [2] => 6 [3] => 1 [4] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 93 [1] => 35 [2] => 20 [3] => 1 [4] => 15 ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 94 [1] => 35 [2] => 25 [3] => 1 [4] => 15 ) )